# How can I summarize a dataframe with counts of only specific values to produce a grouped table with pandas?

Tags: pandas

Please consider the following toy data:

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                'Type': ['a','a','b','b','b','a','a','a','b','b'],
                'Status': ['ft','ft','ft','pt','pt','ft','ft','ft','ft','pt']})
```

I am interested in creating a summary table, grouped by year, with columns I specify holding counts based on strings I select.  For example's sake, I'd like a table that looks like:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1,2],
                   'Type_B_Count': [3,2],
                   'Status_FT_Count': [3,4]})
```

In the R world, I'd use dplyr and get my desired result with:

```
result<-dat%>%
  group_by(Year)%>%
  summarise(Type_B_Count=sum(Type %in% c("b")),
            Status_FT_Count=sum(Status %in% c("ft")))
```

Ideally, I'd like an answer that generalizes so that I could shift code to a string search without much in the way of changes.
(like this in R:

```
    result<-dat%>%
      group_by(Year)%>%
      summarise(Type_B_Count=sum(grepl("b",Type)),
                Status_FT_Count=sum(Status %in% c("ft")))
```

)

I've seen several answers that seem to provide counts of all levels/combinations for the variables of interest, but have yet to find a solution for this specific question.

I'd imagine similar questions get asked quite frequently, but having not found any results that produce this output thus far, here I am. Any help with this question/guidance on getting to the information I'm looking for would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option with custom aggregation ([`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)):

```
out = (
 dat.groupby('Year', as_index=False)
    .agg(**{'Type_B_Count': ('Type', lambda g: g.eq('b').sum()),
            'Status_FT_Count': ('Status', lambda g: g.eq('ft').sum())
         })
)
```

Or:

```
from functools import partial

def count(g, item=None):
    return g.eq(item).sum()

out = (
 dat.groupby('Year', as_index=False)
    .agg(**{'Type_B_Count': ('Type', partial(count, item='b')),
            'Status_FT_Count': ('Status', partial(count, item='ft'))
         })
)
```

Output:

```
   Year  Type_B_Count  Status_FT_Count
0     1             3                3
1     2             2                4
```

Another option using a dictionary:

```
d = {'Type': 'b', 'Status': 'ft'}

out = (
 dat.set_index('Year')
    .eq(d)
    .groupby(level=0).sum()
    .rename(columns=lambda col: f'{col}_{d[col]}_Count')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   Year  Type_b_Count  Status_ft_Count
0     1             3                3
1     2             2                4
```